# check if attribute with a specific value is present in zip/node using zip-filter library or another one

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, clojure-contrib

am new at clojure and would like to know how to check if an attribute with a specific value is present in a zip/node using the zip-filter library.

Let us say I have the following xml content in a file named "myfile.xml"

```
<node1>
  <node2>
      <specialnode type="blabla">
  </node2>
</node1>
```

let us say I have the zipper corresponding to the xml structure shown above,

How can I just test (true or false) if there is a node named "**specialnode**" with an attribute having the value "**blabla**"??

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards. Horace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [tutorial](http://nakkaya.com/2009/12/07/zipping-xml-with-clojure/). The only thing is that the library has moved to https://github.com/clojure/data.zip.